# How to set a specific category page as homepage in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, xml, home-page

I tried to set as a homepage a specific category page but only for a storeview, but I am not sure how to do this.

I have 2 store views and for one of these, I want to set particular category page as homepage.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use switcher for change configuration scope to set different default web urls for multiple store views

[image: Store configuration by scope]

Comment: so if i want to change let's say to baseurl/category , how can i do that? because if a put cms/category/ or i put only category a recive page not found

Comment: how are you set category as home page for your store? i propose to set default url as `catalog/category/view/id/777`

Comment: my category is : www.mywebsite.com/category

Comment: and this is what i recive in backned if i go on the category catalog/category/edit/key/5691aa1a0a0b40b5b54feb3a9bb84ef41c8752907505d433b7ed1f369af6c8c7/id/99/

Comment: you can get category id from category edit page and update Default Web Url setting to `catalog/category/view/id/YOUR_CATEGORY_ID`. For example `catalog/category/view/id/99`

Comment: thanks man for your help! is working fine. sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 5):

Please follow below steps to make category page as home page

**Step 1**
Find out an internal identifier of the category 24. 
[image]

**Step 2**
Locate the General → Web → Default Pages → Default Web URL option in the Stores → Configuration and set it in the following format:

```
catalog/category/view/id/<ID>
```

where ID is an internal identifier of the category. 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to set the ROOT Category as homepage according to the steps @gelanivishal gave. But that doesnt work for the Root Category.

As I could not find a question about setting the Root Category as homepage I will post the solution here:

1. Add a new subcategory to your default root category, and call it "home"
2. In General → Web → Default Pages → Default Web URL put:
   `catalog/category/view/id/<category id of home category>`
3. Of course the new Home Category will appear in your horizontal menu (and category sidebar menu), but you can simply hide these menu items using css: `:nth-child(x)`

Result is a homepage with layout exactly as your category pages.

Dont forget to set the home category to  `Static Block Only` if you dont want to show products.